# Clarifying the meaning of $C^0, C^k,$ and $C^\infty$ functions

Tags: real-analysis

I was reading Loring Tu's book on manifolds and he is describing smooth functions with the $C^k$ notation. I understand that a function is $C^k$ if it has all orders of continuous derivatives for $j \leq k, j \in \{0,1,..k\}$. However he gives an example of $f(x) = x^{1/3}$:

$$
f'(x) = \begin{cases} 
      \frac{1}{3}x^{\frac{-2}{3}} & x\neq 0 \\
      \text{undefined} & x=0 \ 
   \end{cases}
$$

Now, there is an obvious discontinuity at $x=0$ so this function is $C^0$ for the neighborhood of the point $0$. However, for all points excluding $0$, isn't this function $C^\infty$ since you can continuously differentiate this function forever?

Tu says that this function is $C^1$ at points other than 0, however I was not sure if he was saying this in the sense of the function being $C^1$, (but also implying that the function is $C^2, C^3, ...C^\infty$ for $x\neq 0$).

Of course for these functions, the derivatives of all orders approach 0 in the limit rather quickly, but they do exist. I was not sure if the fact that the derivatives vanish in the limit lowers the original functions $C^k$ number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like it's written a bit confusingly. If the function is $C^k$ then it's $C^l$ for any $l<k$, this follows that a function needs to be continuous in order to be derivable. He's already said that it's $C^\infty$ so because of that it's $C^1$ too.

$C^j$ has nothing to do with how fast the derivates approaches zero. They may even diverge. For example $e^{x^2}$ is $C^\infty$ despite the fact that all derivates approaches $\infty$ as $x\to\infty$.

Comment: Yeah, that is what I thought too. So the function is actually $C^\infty$ for $x \neq 0 $, but Tu is correct because a function that is $C^\infty$ is also $C^1$. Thanks for clarifying about the derivative approaching 0 as well, so it is basically about the derivative existing or being defined over the domain.